# Why do my websockets not connect right away when django channels dev server starts up?

Tags: django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I have a django channels project. I'm currently using the

> ASGI/Channels version 2.1.7 development server

When I start up the server, and connect to it with a browser, the HTTP requests start getting served right away, and the HTML page loads in the browser. As soon as the page loads, it tries to establish a websocket connection, which fails.

I'm using [reconnecting-websocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) library, so it keeps trying, and failing. I can see it failing because there are messages in the firefox console that say the connection attempt failed. Refreshing the page doesn't help. After about 30-45 seconds, it starts working. At that point, as long as I keep the development server running, I have zero issues with my websockets - they always connect right away when I load a page that uses them.

The problem doesn't always appear (sometimes it works right away), but when it doesn't, it's always the first 30-45 seconds after starting the development server. It's very annoying to have to wait 30-45 seconds during development every time I need to restart the dev server.

A tcpdump on the server shows websocket requests coming in with a proper destination port, but getting a TCP RST. The failed connection attempts don't show up in the development server logs at all (the ones printed to the screen). It almost seems like Linux is dropping the requests because the socket is busy or something. It's strange though that HTTP requests don't get dropped, but websocket requests do, even though both use the same port.

Anyone have any ideas? Anyone come across this? Any extra debugging I can enable, either on Linux, or on the dev server?

Edit: Using nginx and daphne for deployment, I have no problems. As soon as systemd starts up both nginx and daphne, which only takes about 3 seconds on my raspberry pi, I can load the page, and the web sockets connect perfectly. Only the dev server has issues.